# Objective C - Quadratic equation solver

Tags: objective-c, ios, equation, solver, quadratic

So, im making an app that solves quadratic equations. The main interface simply asks the user to input the values of A, B, and C. The problem is, I'm not getting the right answer. Here's the code:

```
NSString *intStringa = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", a.text];
int aa = [intStringa intValue];
NSString *intStringb = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", b.text];
int bb = [intStringb intValue];
NSString *intStringc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", c.text];
int cc = [intStringc intValue];
double d = ( -(bb) + ( (bb)^2 - (4*aa*cc) ) ^0,5 ) / (2*aa);
double e = ( -(bb) - ( (bb)^2 - (4*aa*cc) ) ^0.5 ) / (2*aa);
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", d];
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", e];
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!!!

Comment: Use `pow` or `sqrt`. `^` is exclusive OR.

Comment: If this is homework please mark it as such (add homework tag).

Comment: double d = ( -(bb) + ( (bb)^2 - (4*aa*cc) ) ^0,5 ) / (2*aa);    apart from ^ another error is 0,5, it should be 0.5

Comment: @rokjarc: Homework tag is deprecated

Comment: thanks, did not notice that. @DanielRuhman: sorry for bad advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use :

There is no `^` operator for root. use `sqrt` or `pow(base,exp)`.

```
double d = ( -bb + sqrt( bb*bb - 4*aa*cc ) ) / (2*aa);
double e = ( -bb - sqrt( bb*bb - 4*aa*cc ) ) / (2*aa);
```

or,

```
double d = ( -bb + pow(( bb*bb - 4*aa*cc ), 0.5) ) / (2*aa);
double e = ( -bb - pow(( bb*bb - 4*aa*cc ), 0.5) ) / (2*aa);
```

Comment: Doesn't `sqrt` return a `double`? That would make the numerator `double` and avoid integer division without explicitly making the denominator a `double`.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `^` for exponentiation in C and related languages (C++, Objective-C, etc) - it's a bitwise XOR operator.

Change:

```
double d = ( -(bb) + ( (bb)^2 - (4*aa*cc) ) ^0,5 ) / (2*aa);
double e = ( -(bb) - ( (bb)^2 - (4*aa*cc) ) ^0.5 ) / (2*aa);
```

to:

```
#include <math.h>

...

double d = - (bb + sqrt(bb * bb - 4 * aa * cc)) / (2 * aa);
double e = - (bb - sqrt(bb * bb - 4 * aa * cc)) / (2 * aa);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no power `^` operator in C. You have to use `pow(b,2)` or simply `b*b`.

And why are you using `stringWithFormat`? Just use `[a.text intValue]`.

```
int aa = [a.text intValue];
int bb = [b.text intValue];
int cc = [c.text intValue];
double d = (-bb + sqrt(bb*bb - 4*aa*cc)) / (2.0*aa);
double e = (-bb - sqrt(bb*bb - 4*aa*cc)) / (2.0*aa);
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", d];
label2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lf", e];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of problems: you are using `^` as an exponentiation operator; it is not. You also have a typo in one of the "exponents": `0,5` instead of `0.5`. I would write your equations as:

```
double d = ( -bb + sqrt( bb*bb - 4*aa*cc ) ) / (2*aa);
double e = ( -bb - sqrt( bb*bb - 4*aa*cc ) ) / (2*aa);
```